# Nvidia driver disables every time I install Ubuntu updates

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on an HP Omen laptop and every time I install Ubuntu updates and I restart the laptop the driver will be disabled and I have to install it again.
For installing the driver I followed these instructions: https://medium.com/@avinchintha/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-and-cuda-10-0-for-rtx-2080-ti-gpu-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-ce32e4edf1c0
And this is the result of my `nvidia-smi`:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.14       Driver Version: 430.14       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2060    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   46C    P8     4W /  N/A |    548MiB /  5931MiB |      3%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0       947      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           155MiB |
|    0      1165      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         276MiB |
|    0      2465      G   ...quest-channel-token=4694289016911940030    48MiB |
|    0      2915      G   ...uest-channel-token=15320141901475657148    66MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So the question is how I can fix this problem?

Comment: You can't fix it. That's what happens when you install that way.

Comment: So what is the correct way?

Comment: The correct way us to install the same version but from the Ubuntu official repo or PPA if the version is newer. 430 is at the graphics drivers PPA.